# Incorrect Comment Count number on main page

Tags: wordpress, themes

after i updated my blog which is powerd by wordpress and deleted all the comments of my blog. i found a wrong thing. each entry of my blog still shows the previous Comment Count number。but i have delted all the comment of the site by the phpmyadmin.  how to make the  Comment Count number to zero?

Comment: Check the post table may be comment count is associated with each post

Comment: what an annoy thing it is, the comment count that associated with each post still has the number. why? how to make them ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also update the `comment_count column` to `0` in `wp_posts` table.

This column contains the number of comment associative with the post since you already deleted all the comments hence you should also update this field value to 0

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_count=0
```